# Extra line space being inserted, unrequested

Tags: tables, spacing, fancyhdr

I have created a survey form over two A4 pages, using tables. I have `fancyhdr` on top of each page and have suppressed the `\maketitle` command.

Both tables have almost exactly the same content (the first is pre-populated with common species, the second is an overflow with empty cells).

The second table is preceded by a vertical space that has not been called, at least not as far as I can see. This is clearly visible in the preview when viewing both pages, side by side.

Additionally, within `fancyhdr`, I would like to add a grey box after the words: Date, Start Time, Surveyor and Weather - to be populated on-site.

The MWE is quite long in order to effectively replicate the upper spacing error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,top=0.75in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\geometry{landscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}



\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{
\small{Date\\Start Time}
}
\chead{
\Large\textbf{Grassland Survey}
}
\rhead{
\small{Surveyor\\Weather}
}
\cfoot{} % page number

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Seravek}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

\title{}
\author{}
%\date{}

\begin{document}
% \maketitle
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Species} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} & \textbf{Total}\\
\hline
Species 1 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 2 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 3 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 4 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 5 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 6 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 7 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 8 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 9 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 10 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 11 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 12 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 13 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 14 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 15 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 16 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 17 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 18 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 19 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 20 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 21 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 22 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 23 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 24 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 25 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 26 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 27 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
Species 28 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

\hline
\textbf{Species} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} & \textbf{Total}\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
& & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't run the example (did you really need non standard fonts and xetex-specific code to show the problem?)

Comment: Your head height is not high enough, it is adjusted by fancyhdr for all pages following the first, hence all content is pushed downwards. Set the headheight to 30pt.

Comment: with standard fonts I get warnings: LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 20.49557pt on input line 102.


LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 20.49557pt on input line 175.


Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 27.68256pt.

Comment: `\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}` has fixed it.
@DavidCarlisle: Having checked, I didn't need non-standard fonts - apologies. I kept them in for consistency with my actual document, in case it affected the vertical space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headhight was too low, package `fancyhdr` was informing you about it. If that is noticed, a package for headers/footers will adjust the headheight for the rest of the document. That is the space that you have benn noticing. Below an adjusted header, using package `scrlayer-scrpage`. Package `xcolor` was used to geet some gray rule to indicate that something should be filled.

[image: pwdrDatasheet]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,top=0.75in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\geometry{landscape}



\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\fillin}{{\color{gray!20}\rule[-3pt]{3cm}{.9\baselineskip}}}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ihead{\parbox{5cm}{\raggedleft
    \linespread{1.3}
    \small Date \fillin\\Start Time \fillin
}
}
\chead{%
    \Large\textbf{Grassland Survey}%
}
\ohead{\parbox{5cm}{\raggedleft
    \linespread{1.3}
    \small Surveyor \fillin\\Weather \fillin
}%
}

%\usepackage{showframe}


\setlength{\headheight}{34pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Species} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} & \textbf{Total}\\
        \hline
        Species 1 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 2 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 3 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 4 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 5 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 6 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 7 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 8 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 9 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 10 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 11 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 12 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 13 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 14 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 15 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 16 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 17 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 18 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 19 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 20 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 21 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 22 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 23 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 24 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 25 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 26 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 26 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        Species 26 & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular*}

    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

        \hline
        \textbf{Species} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} & \textbf{Total}\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular*}


\end{document}
```